# How to parse Goodreads API's response in XML?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use Goodreads APIs for my sideproject but facing some problem. The below URL returns XML data. If I use `datatype: 'xml'` then I get cross-domain error and thats why I've used 'jsonp' but still gets `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error. Am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'http://www.goodreads.com/user/show/userid.xml?key=developerKey&id=userId, 
  method : 'get', 
  dataType : 'jsonp', 
  success : function (data) {
    console.log($.parseXML(data));
  }
});
```

Comment: Here's [one possible solution](http://weedygarden.net/2011/01/consuming-remote-xml-as-jsonp/).

Comment: @MichaelMior : No luck. "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: That can't happen because the proxy script would be running on your on domain. In that case you would just make a regular JSON request to the same domain.

Comment: I'm running the above code locally and the url returns xml data. Upon making a regular JSON/text/xml request, I get "cross-domain" error.

Comment: This would suggest that you can't make any AJAX requests to your own domain. In which case, something strange is going on.

Answer (score 6):

Use an external *proxy* that supports CORS to make the goodreads request.

At least Yahoo YQL can be used as a proxy, as done in this example code (it's free, no API key needed!). YQL returns the Goodreads XML response wrapped inside `/query/results`.

```
var url = "http://www.goodreads.com/user/show/userid.xml" +
          "?key=developerKey&id=userId";

$.get("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    {
        q: "select * from xml where url=\""+url+"\"",
        format: "xml"
    },
    function(xml){
        // contains XML with the following structure:
        // <query>
        //   <results>
        //     <GoodreadsResponse>
        //        ...
        console.log(xml);
    }
);
```

More about YQL in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579158/1068385

Answer (score 0):

Trying using 'application/xml' instead.

Comment: No luck. "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Answer (score -1):

(1) The cross-domain error message suggests that your app isn't correctly authenticated to Goodreads.

```
url : 'http://www.goodreads.com/user/show/userid.xml?key=developerKey&id=userId,
```

is missing its closing quote and doesn't evaluate the variables for the query string.  I take it you mean

```
url : 'http://www.goodreads.com/user/show/userid.xml?key=' + developerKey + '&id=' + userId,
```

(2) It looks like you are getting a response from the Goodreads server, but you also might want to try this to make sure you are getting something that you expect:

```
dataType: 'text'
```

and just console.log() the data without parsing it.

Comment: No luck. "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."