# Amazon CloudSearch query

Tags: jquery, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am at a lost on how to query my Amazon CloudSearch from a static HTML page. Although the documentation is good there are no examples beyond copying and pasting a URL in a browser.

What I would like is an HTML page in S3, so no server side code allowed, to have a text field form that when the search button is clicked fires to my CloudSearch end point and returns the results

CloudSearch responds with JSON, so will have to parse that and make a table of the results.

So far I have been working with a saved JSON of the results locally and using Jquery to read the JSON file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $.getJSON('search.json', function(data) {

    var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in data.hit) {
            output+="<li>" + data.hit[i].id+ "</li>";
        }

        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;

        console.log(data);
  });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives me the ID for the record.

But when I try and change the URL to the CloudSearch end point I get no data back. Having read and gone round in circles I believe it is because of CORS.

However, Amazon's documentation just say to use an HTTP GET on the endpoint but how do I build that into my HTML page.

Sorry for such a basic question

Comment: Did you configure the access to your search domain: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configureaccess.html ?

Comment: Hi Guy - yes I can results if I use a URL in a browser, so the access works. It is just how to search and parse the response from an HTML page. Do you use it?

Comment: Note that the IP of the caller is different when you run it from EC2 server in your AJAX call. I use it differently, as the results from CloudSearch are not presented from the response itself. I use it just to give me back the IDs of the documents (and the facets).

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.You need to create an xml configuration file like this.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: I have added CORS to my S3 bucket and I get a red 200 response in Firebug, so there still seems to be a problem

Comment: I now have an HTML page successfully requesting a JSON from a different S3 bucket and displaying the results. So it is definitely something with CloudSearch and not CORS on my S3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

CloudSearch doesn't currently support CORS, so your browser won't allow you to contact CloudSearch.

If you don't want to run a server, you'll need to find a proxy for your requests. You might take a look at this:

[Is there a free JSON proxy server which supports CORS or JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537601/is-there-a-free-json-proxy-server-which-supports-cors-or-jsonp)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an html form with all the pieces for the search; just make sure it ends up constructing the proper url, for example:

http://search-YOURDOMAIN-RANDOMID.REGION.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=THESEARCHPHRASE&q.parser=simple&start=0&size=30&return=COMMA%2cSEPARATED%2cLIST_OF_FIELDS

which would correspond to a form like:

```
<form action="http://search-YOURDOMAIN-RANDOMID.YOURREGION.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search" method="get">

   <label>Search: <input name="q" /></label>
   <input type="hidden" name="q.parser" value="simple" />

   <label>How many results? <select name="size">
      <option>10</option>
      <option>20</option>
   </select></label>

   // other dropdowns, hidden inputs etc corresponding to `start`, `return`, etc

   <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

If you need help figuring out what you should be submitting, inspect the Network traffic (Chrome > F12 > Network tab) when you're on the CloudSearch Dashboard "Run a Test Search" (https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/home?region=YOURREGION#search,YOURDOMAIN).  Or read more for search url examples on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching.html

Answer (score 0):

Created an angularjs project that demos this and added to git hub.  You need CORS-anywhere to route properly to the domain.

https://github.com/tkntobfrk/amazon-cloudsearch-angular

project uses suggesters to search domain data and populate the input field with autocomplete data. Uses bootstrap.ui typeahead.

Answer (score 0):

To enable CORS to cloudsearch API, you can use AWS API Gateway HTTPProxy to front end your cloudsearch end point.

AWS API Gateway allows you to enable CORS.

For my configuration I have added Passthrough for these fields while defining the end point: 
start,sort,q.options,q.parser,return,fq,q,size

You can map each of these params like this:

```
method.request.querystring.start
method.request.querystring.sort
method.request.querystring.q.options
etc.
```